# Is there any desktop notifier application for bitcoin prices?

Tags: trading, exchange-rate

There's a nice C2DM push based notifier for android but I'd like to know if there is one for the desktop environment, ideally linux?

Does anyone know if one exists?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a solution which will run on linux, then there's always a the `wget` command:

```
wget -q -O - https://mtgox.com/code/ticker.php
```

You can run it in a loop in a terminal :)

Under the xfce desktop environment you could use the `genmon` panel plugin and feed it Mt. Gox's last trade data. Speaking of which, I think I'll do that myself. :)

Comment: just made a quick shell script that i call from the genmon plugin. simple one-liner to grab the ticker and pull out last price: wget -q -O - https://mtgox.com/code/ticker.php --no-check-certificate | awk -F"," '{print $8}' | awk -F":" '{print $2}'

Comment: When I visit `https://mtgox.com/code/ticker.php`, it says the API is deprecated.....

Comment: Is there one that can use data from bitcoincharts.com? So I can monitor the price on localbtc?

Answer (score 1):

While it's not necessarily a *desktop* notifier, there *is* a functional web-app notifier recently [publicized on the forums](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=57736.0): http://www.bitcoin-tools.de/

From the site:

> It is nothing more than a simple alert-system which alerts you
>   whenever the buy, last or sell is reaching a defined level.

The tool includes audio alerts and user-definable limits.