# Is there a Bitcoin price alert application that can use data from BitcoinCharts.com?

Tags: trading, exchange-rate, windows

Is there a Bitcoin price alert application that can use data from BitcoinCharts.com?  Something like a windows desktop alert is what I have in mind.

I need this as I am trying to monitor prices of different exchanges such as localbitcoins.

If not then I may write a quick application for it and post it here.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "alert" can you be more specific?  Send an email? have (insert specified OS or device) pop up a notification? Etc

Comment: Also, check out this similar question.  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/is-there-any-desktop-notifier-application-for-bitcoin-prices?rq=1

There's a link to a webapp http://www.bitcoin-tools.de/

Comment: @NeilNeyman Thanks but that web app only uses mtgox data. And by alert I just mean any form of alert. Desktop alert would be best. I am thinking about writing a C# app that sits in the system tray polling bitcoincharts. Something like that would be ideal

Answer (score 1):

The wiki maintains a list of [currently available software tools](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Software).

I don't see anything on there per-se but it might be an included feature in one of the pc tools.

But I say go ahead and write one if you have the time and desire.  It's nice to have options even if that feature already exists somewhere. I'm mostly Mac desktop guy these days so I'm a fan of multi-platform tools when possible. But that's tough to do for the kind of thing you're taking about. But if you open-source it there's always room for someone to port it or expand upon it!

Answer (score 0):

If you know a little bit of scripting and you are in Linux, you can make a simple script (using curl or wget for instance) that do exactly what you want. Check [this](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/) out.

Answer (score 0):

I use Bitcoin Checker in my phone, it has a plethora of exchanges but it doesn't have Bitcoincharts, most probably because Bitcoincharts doesn't seem to be a Bitcoin exchange, thus being irrelevant for the use of a price alert app.

In this open source app you can track Bitcoin price in different exchanges and set the alert to a % of variation from the last price, I think it is a great app.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this [bitcoin price alert](http://www.coinpatrol.com) service. It isn't tied specifically to bitcoincharts, but it supports some of the bigger exchanges and can send notifications through text or e-mail.